# Define a function to generate html pages in python

Tags: python, html, csv

trying to create several web pages that contains tables from the read csv file and I tried to define a function to create html web pages rather than writing the same codes many times.

read my csv file:

```
infile = open("new.csv", "r")
data = []
for line in infile:
    cols = line.split(",")
    Oposition = cols[0]
    Winner = cols[1]
    Margin = cols[2]
    Ground = cols[3]
    Year = cols[4]
    pair = (Oposition, Winner, Margin, Ground, Year)
    data.append(pair)
infile.close()
```

so far my codes are:

```
page = """<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>abc</title>
  <style>
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
body {
    background-image: url("2014.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>{{heading}}</h1>
  {{paragraph}}
  <p><a href = "index.html">Back to main page</a></p>
  <table border="1"><tr><th>Oposition</th><th>Winner</th><th>Margin</th><th>Ground</th><th>Year</th></tr>

"""

out1=page.format(heading = "2012 Stats", paragraph = "<p>aaaaaaa</p>")
out2 = page.format(heading = "2013 Stats", paragraph = "<p>bbbbb</P>")
out3 = page.format(heading = "2014 Stats", paragraph = "<p>cccc</P>")
out4 = page.format(heading = "2015 Stats", paragraph = "<p>ddddCSK</p>")

def write_html_file(filename, body):
    out = open(filename, "w")
    out.write(body)

write_html_file("2012.html",out1)
write_html_file("2013.html",out2)
write_html_file("2014.html",out3)
write_html_file("2015.html",out4)

for r in data:
    if ''.join(r[4].split()) == "2012":
        Oposition = r[0]
        Winner = r[1]
        Margin = r[2]
        Ground=r[3]
        Year = r[4]
        out1.write("<tr> <td>" + Oposition+ '</td><td> '+ Winner+'</td><td> '+Margin+'</td><td> '+Ground+' </td><td>'+ Year+ " </td></tr>")
    elif ''.join(r[4].split()) == "2013":
        Oposition = r[0]
        Winner = r[1]
        Margin = r[2]
        Ground=r[3]
        Year = r[4]
        out2.write("<tr> <td>" + Oposition+ '</td><td> '+ Winner+'</td><td> '+Margin+'</td><td> '+Ground+' </td><td>'+ Year+ " </td></tr>")
    elif ''.join(r[4].split()) == "2014":
        Oposition = r[0]
        Winner = r[1]
        Margin = r[2]
        Ground=r[3]
        Year = r[4]
        out3.write("<tr> <td>" + Oposition+ '</td><td> '+ Winner+'</td><td> '+Margin+'</td><td> '+Ground+' </td><td>'+ Year+ " </td></tr>")
    elif ''.join(r[4].split()) == "2015":
        Oposition = r[0]
        Winner = r[1]
        Margin = r[2]
        Ground=r[3]
        Year = r[4]
        out4.write("<tr> <td>" + Oposition+ '</td><td> '+ Winner+'</td><td> '+Margin+'</td><td> '+Ground+' </td><td>'+ Year+ " </td></tr>")

def output(a):
    a.write("</table>  </body>\n")
    a.write("</html>\n")
    a.close()

output(out1)
output(out2)
output(out3)
output(out4)
```

im trying to make tables according to years 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015 and make html pages that contains each of them. just cant figure out.
Any help or other option? Much appreciated
I get an error message saying:

```
---> 25 page1 = page.format(heading = "2012 Stats", paragraph = "<p>aaaa</p>")
KeyError: '\n    text-align'
```

Comment: I get this error message : ---> 38 out1=page.format(heading = "2012 Stats", paragraph = "<p>aaaaa</p>") KeyError: '\n    text-align'

Comment: Have you looked at something like `jinja2` where you define an HTML template, pass it a context, and then it builds the document for you?

Comment: It looks like your out2 and out3 end with uppercase closing paragraph tags.

Comment: corrected it. but still getting same error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Python's built-in [string format syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) is a variable enclosed by single paramthesis. That's why '\n    text-align' is regarded as a key whereas it was intended to be a css style.

**Solution**

You can go ahead to escape your css snippets but I would not recommend it, because the html text will not be readable and will be difficult to maintain.

Hence, please use a template engine to help. There are many template engines: [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/), [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/).. etc. Since I am more familiar with the first one, let me show you how to get **page1** working::

```
from jinja2 import Environment

env = Environment()
page_template = env.from_string(page)
page1 = page_template(heading="2012 Stats", paragraph="<p>aaaaaaa</p>")
```

And you will need to install jinja2:

```
$ pip install jinja2
```

**Alternative solution**

You can use my library [pyexcel](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [pyexcel-text](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-text) to get a html table rendered for you. The sample code is:

```
import pyexcel as p

sheet = p.get_sheet(file_name='new.csv')
sheet.colnames = ['Oposition', 'Winner', 'Margin', 'Ground', 'Year']
sheet.name = "2012 Stats"
print(sheet.html)
```

To run above code, you need to install these two additional packages:

```
$ pip install pyexcel pyexcel-text
```

Comment: yes i could make it work using jinja2. appreciate a lot